# JAVA: How do I add two processed values with same name declared but different values

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to sum up the two "final scores" of player 1 into a total score of player1 that I can compare with another player's total score later.

```
int player11, player12, player21, player22;
int score1;
int score2 = 0;

Random random = new Random();
int i=0;
do {
    do {
        System.out.println("Player 1 rolls the dice");
        player11 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        player12 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        score1 = player11 + player12;
        System.out.println(player11 + "\t" + player12 + "\t" + score1);
        if (player11 == 1 && player12 == 1) {
            score1 = score1 * 2;
            
        } else if ((player11 % 2 != 0 && player12 % 2 != 0) && (player11 != 1 && player12 != 1)) {
            score1 -= 5;
        } else if (player11 == 6 && player12 == 6) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 rerolls the dice");
            score1 = 0;
        }
    } while (player11 == 6 && player12 == 6);
    
    System.out.println("Final Score: " + score1);
    i++;
} while (i<2);
```

Comment: Add each computed value into the total immediately after you have computed it.

Answer (score 1):

So far what I have understood is you want to add the score after each iteration right ? In that case you can just use a temp to store the score for the calculation and then add it after the inner do-while loop is complete. Like following:

```
do {
    int temp = 0; //New variable to temporarily save scores
      do {
        System.out.println("Player 1 rolls the dice");
        player11 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        player12 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        temp = player11 + player12; //instead of score we're saving it in temp
        /* your code continued..... 
        remember to swap score1 with temp at every place
        .....
        .....
        */
        }
    } while (player11 == 6 && player12 == 6);
    score1 = score1 + temp; // Finally we add it in the score1 variable
    System.out.println("Final Score: " + score1);
    i++;
} while (i<2);
```

I hope this resolves the trivial issue. Also I think you didn't initialize the score1 variable which might cause issues.

Comment: Thank you for your help and reminder, it does resolves my issue :D